# Contact Form in Hebrew- Weird Symbols

Tags: php, character-encoding

I made a form for contacting me on my website.
This is the php code:

```
    <?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    "name: $name \n\n email: $email_address \n\n\n $message";

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact_thanks.html');
} 
?>
```

When I use the form on the website, I receive a mail with weird symbols. That is because I write in Hebrew in the form- English letters are delivered well.
When I change "myemail" to another mail, the message is delivered well, even in Hebrew, but I want the message to pass to the first mail.

I changed many times the encoding, but none seems to solve the problem, perhaps I hadn't tried the correct one yet.

I am not the one who wrote the code and my I don't know php well, so please give me answers that are easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify content encoding in your mail header. For this reason, add this line:

```
$headers .= "\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```